# Get product name in my orders (order history page)

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order, customer-account

How can I get the name of a product in the order history page? I copied the view order code in but it's not working.

```
$_order = $block->getOrder()
<?php $_items = $_order->getItemsCollection(); ?>
<?php foreach ($_items as $_item){ ?>
<?php echo $block->getItemHtml($_item) }?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento save order items name at **`sales_order_item`**  table's at name columns.So you have order item object then using  `getName()` function for getting  product name at any where.

> ```
> <?php  $_order = $block->getOrder();
> foreach ($_items as $_item){ ?>
> <?php echo $_item->getName(); ?>
> <?php echo $block->getItemHtml($_item) 
> }?>
> ```

Comment: getting error call to a member function getItemsCollection() on null

Comment: may be you did not add `$_order = $block->getOrder()`

Answer (score 1):

You copied wrong code
you need to copy rendered item data from /module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml

```
<?php $_item = $block->getItem()
 $block->setPriceDataObject($_item) ?><tr>

<?php $i = 0;
$columns = $block->getColumns();
$lastItemNumber = count($columns) ?>
<?php foreach ($columns as $columnName => $columnClass):?>
    <?php $i++; ?>
    <td class="<?php echo /* @noEscape */ $columnClass?><?php /* @noEscape */ echo ($i === $lastItemNumber ? ' last' : '')?>"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getColumnHtml($_item, $columnName) ?></td>
<?php endforeach; ?></tr>
```

get item with column name, will allow you to get product name.

Comment: its not working @Ronak Chauhan

Comment: have you called this function : $_items = $block->getItemsCollection()

Comment: /vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/items.phtml

this file called rendered file so you need to pass that item data through 
this  : 
$block->getItemHtml($_item)